# MigrationHistory as entity in DbContext in Entity Framework 7

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations, .net-core

I'm trying to get the (by Entity Framework generated) table `__EFMigrationsHistory`as an entity into my database context:

[image]

In Entity Framework 6 this worked fantastically, but did anyone tried it in EntityFramework 7?

What I tried is, to just add a new class `__EFMigrationsHistory` - but it'd be too easy - `there is already a table named __EFMigrationsHistory in the database` (thanks...)

Then I read about that HistoryRow, I shall inherit a class from. So I created the class

```
public class MigrationsHistory : HistoryRow 
{ 
    //... constructor etc.
}
```

started a migration and: I got two migration-history-tables (but only the original one works)

So I read on and searched for interfaces and classes to implement/inherit from. I found `SqlServerHistoryRepository` - looks nice. I created an new database context inheriting from `SqlServerHistoryRepository` (like I'd have done it in EF6). - But this is not a context-class, so I can not add it in Startup.cs (like I did with my default applicationcontext)

So I checked the `DbContext` for maybe add the history-table somewhere (like in EF6), but there is nothing for adding the table to my context.

So: Anyone already tried to add the migration-history to his context? Anyone was successful?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whilst I experimented with bricelam's answer with no success with EF Core 2.0, 
in 
[Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore](https://apisof.net/catalog/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.RelationalDatabaseFacadeExtensions.GetAppliedMigrations(DatabaseFacade)) there's a method;

```
// .NET Core 1.0 + Platform Extensions
// Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational, Version=1.1.0.0, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60

namespace Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
{
    public static class RelationalDatabaseFacadeExtensions
    {
        public static IEnumerable<string> GetAppliedMigrations(this DatabaseFacade databaseFacade);
    }
}
```

Call it as follows;

```
var dbcontext = new DbContext();
IEnumerable<string> history = dbcontext.Database.GetAppliedMigrations();
```

Answer (score 2):

Mapping to the table by name should work (it *is* that easy), you just need to ensure you don't try to re-create it (e.g. by accidentally calling `DbContext.Database.EnsureCreate()`)

```
class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<AppliedMigration> AppliedMigrations { get; set; }
}

[Table("__EFMigrationsHistory")]
class AppliedMigration
{
    [Column("MigrationId")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [Column("ProductVersion")]
    public string EFVersion { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I never did recreate the database. I set up a new project, ef7, migrations, added a first one, and he tries to add it twice. I'd have to manipulate the generated migration-file, but i think it's the wrong way to solve this.

Comment: Let me try this tomorrow again, and i come back to this answere :) would be nice to see this working.

Comment: Modify the generated migration! Yes, this is the *right* way to solve this problem (until [#2725](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/2725) is implemented)

Comment: Mhh modifying the generated migration doesn't sound like the correct way. So I think this is a solution to solve the problem - this is more a bug/missing or incomplete feature for ef core accessing the migration table via code. Isn't it?

Comment: We've added `DbContext.Database.GetAppliedMigrations()` in 1.1. Before that, you could use the `IHistoryRepository` service directly. In general, having the applied migrations be part of your domain model seems pretty rare.

Comment: If you want to manage the database with the application, and have no access to the server, it is neccessary. Rollback migrations, update the DB... and so on.  But okay, thanks for your info, I'm trying to fix it this way. :)